# WordPress Prev and Next not working for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type where I don't want the posts to be visible individually, so I set,

```
'publicly_queryable' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'custom-page-slug'),
```

I then have the following query on the page:

```
<?php 
$paged = 2;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'sample_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged, order => "DESC" );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  echo '<h2>' . esc_html( get_the_title() ) . '</h2>';
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

My issue is, when I try to use `get_next_posts_link()` and `get_previous_posts_link()`, they simply link to the same page (they don't go to `page/2` or `page/1`).

Here is my code for the prev and next links:

```
        <?php if ($loop->max_num_pages > 1) { // check if the max number of pages is greater than 1  ?>
            <div class="clearfix prev-next-arrows">
                <nav class="prev-next-posts">
                    <div class="next-posts-link">
                        <?php echo get_next_posts_link( 'Next Page &raquo;', $query->max_num_pages ); // display older posts link ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="prev-posts-link">
                        <?php echo get_previous_posts_link( '&laquo; Previous Page' ); // display newer posts link ?>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Anyone know what would be wrong with my current setup?

Thanks

Comment: Did you put the code for the prev and next post in the loop ?

Comment: No it's outside of the loop, the links show up, that's why I think it's something wrong with the way my custom post type is set up.

Comment: Put them inside the loop, else how could it know what is the current post and so the prev and next post ?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `echo get_next_posts_link(...)` and `echo get_previous_posts_link(...)` you should use `next_posts_link(...)` and `previous_posts_link(...)` (without the `echo` and without the `get_` part, at least that's how it works in my websites.

Also, before you define the arguments, insert this line (instead of `$paged = 2;`):

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Comment: Tried that, got the same result. Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry, not luck with that either

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had the following in my custom post type args:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'post-type-slug')
```

It was the same slug as the page I had the loop on